# How to roll back transaction after error occurs

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project which is creating a graph object of the Journal Transaction screen and entering data.  I would like to know the best way of handling any error with the ability to rollback all entries if this occurs.

Here's a snippet of how I'm inserting rows (with some code not shown):

```
        Batch batch;
        GLTran tran;

        if (gltran.BatchNbr != lastbatchnbr)
        {
            batch = new Batch();
            batch.BranchID = branchID;
            batch.Description = "InterCo JE from " + osd.String01 + "Module AP Batch " + gltran.BatchNbr;
            batch.FinPeriodID = gltran.FinPeriodID;
            jegraph.BatchModule.Insert(batch);
            jegraph.Persist();
        }



        tran = new GLTran();
        tran.AccountID = accountID;
        tran.SubID = subID;
        tran.TranDate = gltran.TranDate;
        tran.RefNbr = gltran.RefNbr;
        tran.CuryDebitAmt = gltran.DebitAmt;
        tran.CuryCreditAmt = gltran.CreditAmt;

        jegraph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(tran);
        jegraph.Persist();
```

Should I not persist until all entries (inserts) are done (for several batches) - and somehow roll back before any persist is done?

A code example would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Persisting code should be wrapped in a transaction if you want all persists to occur together unless an Error is received. So you could wrap the code you have (2 separate persists) within the same transaction using PXTransactionScope as shown below.

```
using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
{
    // Persisting code here...

    ts.Complete();
}
```

When an error is received it will automatically rollback or do not call ts.Complete()